# Check if input is integer in 05AB1E

Tags: input, conditional-statements, 05ab1e

I want to check if the input is a positive integer in the language [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E). This should output something that acts as a boolean. For example,

- "oof" ==> false
- 7.5   ==> false
- 19    ==>  true

...

Is there a way to do this? Numeric strings can output true or false. It depends on the nature of the input.

Comment: In what language are you trying to do this? What have you tried so far and what in particular are you stuck on?

Comment: The question mentions `05AB1E`. That's the language. I know that `sI` does this in Pyth, but I'm more new to this language.

Comment: I see, that was far from clear, and it's a pretty obscure language. Clarified that for you.

Comment: `.ï` does that in 05AB1E

Comment: @CommandMaster It sure does work! Thank you!